# MySQL query failed in v5.7 while works in v4.1

Tags: mysql

I need to migrate an old application Bugzilla 2.8 to a new server. It's using Perl and Mysql 4.1 as backend database. The application works with current configuration. I have to install Mysql 5.7 on new server. I did a dump of Mysql 4.1 database and imported into Mysql 5.7. Bugzilla failed with new database.I can see following simplified query failed in Mysql 5.7. The error is error code 1054. Unknown column 'bugs.bug_id' in 'on clause'. If I remove profiles AS map_assigned_to the query will work. However the query is dynamically generated by Bugzilla. Is there any configuration I can change to make it working in Mysql 5.7?

SELECT bugs.bug_id, bugs.bug_severity, bugs.priority
FROM bugs, profiles AS map_assigned_to
LEFT JOIN bug_group_map  ON bug_group_map.bug_id = bugs.bug_id

Comment: You should always add your tables with data, or else it is hard to help

Comment: What do you mean by "work"? Does the query fail and give you an error? If so, please edit the question to provide the error message. Does the query just return results you weren't expecting? If so, please edit the question to include your _expected_ results, as well as what you're _actually_ getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unclear `profiles AS map_assigned_to` table full join mixed in implicit join syntax mixed with explicit join syntax.

This should not work  in any version - be sure you really need this profiles cross join or try to explain better your query goal to build a proper query (for both the versions).

```
  SELECT bugs.bug_id
    , bugs.bug_severity
    , bugs.priority
    , bugs.bug_status
    , bugs.resolution 
  FROM bugs   
  LEFT JOIN bug_group_map  ON bug_group_map.bug_id = bugs.bug_id
```

Comment: I know where the problem is. However the same query is working in Mysql 4.1. And this query is dynamically generated.

Comment: then  .. you need  change the generator  ..  in msqyl 5.7  the the mixed  sintax for join implict and explict isi not allowed ..

Comment: You are right. I found the official explanation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html. I have rewrote the query in Bugzilla. Now the application is up running. Thanks!